# How to display namespace text, on class pages, with Doxygen

Tags: class, automation, namespaces, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen v1.8.16, on my C# class library. I’d like all of my documented class pages to include text that states what namespace it is part of.  I COULD accomplish this manually by adding all the documented class in a namespace to a group using the /ingroup namespaceGroupName command, in the class's comments.  But as this seems awfully redundant, time-consuming and error-prone, I’m wondering:

**Is there any way to configure the display of a class's namespace, on a class's page (for all classes in all namespaces), without manually editing/listing each class?**

Currently, what I'm looking for can only be found on my alphabetical “Class Index” page, where it shows both the class name and the namespace it belongs to, with text as links, in this form:   `ClassName (Name.Space)`

I should mention, I intentionally set the option in my config file:  `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES`

While changing this option to `NO` would technically work, it would affect more than just the documented class page, which I don’t want to do.  (I would also prefer to have the namespace as a separate text item, like in parenthesis or a different font/size/line.)

Edit:  Here is an example of the standard output, and in orange, the change/addition to the output that I'm looking for.  (I realize the namespace is displayed in the menu right above the class title, but I need it in the same area as the other groups.)

[image]

Comment: A small example together together with an image of what you get and indicated what you would like to get would probably help. At the moment I think "this is not possible" but an example might shine a light on it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look albert, I've updated the question with an image.  If this can't be done automatically, I'll just do it manually with groups.  (Figured I'd spend some internet points on a bounty, before spending the time ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a way to do it, but maybe someone else has an idea.